# Storing int value into char p[] index

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

Been stuck on a problem. figured out my issue. I have looked online quite a bit and have read many possible solutions, but nothing seems to work for me.

I have this program, lets call it `test.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int x = 21345;
    char p[10];
    p[0] = x;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    printf("%d", p[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

As you would guess, I want the two `printf` statements to have the same output. Instead, I get the following output...

```
21345
97
```

I need `21345` to be at `p[0]`, and when I call `printf("%d", p[0]);`
 It needs to print out `21345`, not `97`

Any help? :(

EDIT:
Looks like you guys answered, thanks! Changing to `int p[10]` would solve the problem. I have another complication though, I also need to be able to store strings inside the indexes of `p`, along with ints.. how should I tackle this?

Comment: can you change char p[10]; to int p[10];?

Comment: check `CHAR_MAX` in `#include <limits.h>`

Comment: That does work, Dr.Stitch.
If i was to change it to `int p[10]`, would I be able to concatenate strings into the indexes of `p`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char` does not have the same type as `int` and is not identical in number of bits. You would need `int p[10];` for that to work.

Comment: Well that does solve the problem I posted!
If I was to change it to `int p[10]`, would I be able to put concatenate strings into the indexes of `p`?

Comment: What do you mean by concatenate strings? Do you have an example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of signed chars, they take 1 byte each, the max value would be 127 and minimum -128. Now the x's value takes more bytes to represent, there is an overflow, and it truncates the leftmost bits,

```
21345 has the binary representation:           0101 0011 0110 0001

now discard the leftmost byte and you get:               0110 0001   which is 97
```

Answer (score 0):

`char` store only 1 byte value so that you are getting that output. If you change `char p[10]` to `int p[10]` you will get output.

Answer (score 0):

`char` is simply not big enough to store `21345`. Therefore compiler  takes just low 8 bits and puts them into `char`, so it becomes `97`. When passing to printf it will convert it back to `int` but the highest bits are already lost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use int array instead of char
It should be like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int x = 21345;
    int p[10];
    p[0] = x;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    printf("%d", p[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
21345
21345
```

Well if you want to use same array for strings too, use 2 dimensions char array
because you can store a integer value in 4 characters array correctly.
so you need to use p[10][4] 
Now store each byte of int in corresponding char array index

```
p[0][0] = (x >> (8*0)) & 0xff;
p[0][1] = (x >> (8*1)) & 0xff;
p[0][2] = (x >> (8*2)) & 0xff;
p[0][3] = (x >> (8*3)) & 0xff;
```